# CSWP Sorting by Date

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, cswp

I am trying to get the CSWP to display all events and sorting using Start Date.
The problem is that the "StartDate" field doesn't show up in the list of properties to Sort by in the Sorting Tab of the Advanced view of the query.
Any idea what needs to be done here?
It is a sharePoint Office 365 site. Publishing feature is enabled.

Comment: @RanserSingh is correct, `StartDate` is one of the few OOB fields that doesn't have a Managed Property set up by default, so you have to set it up yourself (and make sure it's Sortable) to make it available in the CSWP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 options:

1. Make sure that the field you are sorting on is defined as a Managed 
   property with the Sortable option checked

**(or)**

2. Create a result source
   with the same query and sorting and apply that to the CSWP

**Note:** In SharePoint Online, not all the options for system managed properties are available. If you’d like to set up a new managed property, you need to use an existing, unused managed property, and rename it by using an Alias. There are many managed properties available for this purpose. They have names such as "RefinableString00" and "RefinableDate19."

Comment: The Issue is that in SharePoint online you cannot add a date time managed property.
And Result Source Sort properties are exactly the same one available for the CSWP. Neither has the start date property

Comment: Updated answer above

Comment: It worked by using the existing unused managed properties. Steps here: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Manage-the-search-schema-in-SharePoint-Online-d4fab46d-ba41-4c03-9d4c-32b5b33198b6?CTT=1&CorrelationId=01a12eed-0e13-4c5c-bffb-9b979b6ec801&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US#__ref341260321